# mezzanine: is it possible to organize parent menu on top and branch menu on the left?

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'd like to organize the web page of my mezzanine website as follows:

1. The parent menu is on the top (not shown on the left side)
2. The left sidebar is empty initially. If a button in the parent menu is clicked, its associated branch menu will show up on the left side bar.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in settings.py

```
PAGES_MENU_SHOW_ALL=False
```

for more u can visit http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/configuration.html